# Amazon Route 53 Domain A record Issue

Tags: amazon-route53

I have registered a domain called thepostcloud.com (route53)and when tried to create an A record with public IP to host a web site its not able to set , all displaying in route53 console. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

To create records on AWS Route 53:

- go to Route 53 page
- click on Hosted Zones
- click on your domain name
- choose the button *create record set*
- on the right panel fill "name" field and "value" (default for A record)
- click create